# How to return object to UiPath in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, uipath

I am trying to return an object from function Find123. I have called it from sub procedure Retrieve123.

When I comple it says function not defined and it highlights the CObj method.

Could you tell me a way to convert integer or string into object and return it in VBA?

```
Sub Retrieve123()
    Call Find123()
End Sub

Function Find123()As Object
    Dim val As String
    val="100"
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj=CObj(val)
    Set Find123 = obj
End Function
```

This is how I get the error message
[image]

When I assign the string value into the function it gives this type mismatch error.
[image]

I need to convert the string into object because in UiPath we can only return type object as the Invoke VBA activity's output is object type.

Comment: There is no such command as `CObj` you are just making up stuff. Objects are CODE. You cannot convert a scalar variable into an object. It is meaningless operation.

Comment: okay. I need to return a object. could you please tell me how to do that ? @CatCat

Comment: You'll have to make an object. Objects are **CODE**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to convert anything to an object, yet UiPath treats return values from the `Invoke VBA` activity as objects (since it wouldn't know what is being returned). You can safely return a primitive type from your function - an `integer` in your case - store it in a object-typed variable in UiPath, and then cast it to integer again.

Here's a general example. Note that `result` is of type `object` while `i` is an `integer`. Inside the `Assign` activity, `i` is being cast to an `integer`.

VB.NET equivalent:

```
i = CType(result, Integer)
```

[image: Type Conversion in UiPath]